# Crystal Report, set Page Number Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I need to set the page number of the report I have generated dynamically.

For that I have used a text Object and pass the page number when loading data.For an example if I passed 55, page number text Object will display it as 55.

My problem is if the report continues to 2nd page the page numbering format need to be changed. If the page number I have passed is 55, and if the page continues to 2 pages, then page 1 should be 55A, page 2 should be 55B.

How can I do it?

Because I am unable to identify whether the page continues to a 2nd page.

Comment: Does 55 come from a parameter, as craig's code suggests?

Answer (score 0):

This approach might work:

Create a formula named 'repeated':

```
//{@repeated}
WhilePrintingRecords;
If InRepeatedGroupHeader Then True Else False;
```

Place this field in the group header (whatever group causes a 'spill over') and suppress it.

Create a formula named 'page number:

```
//{@page number}
WhilePrintingRecords;
If {@repeated}=True Then
  //logic to append 
  ToText({?page number parameter),"#") + ' continued'
Else
  ToText({?page number parameter},"#")
```

Place field in Page Footer.